# Query Builder for Angular2

Tags: angular, npm, zurb-foundation, query-builder

Is there any query builder out there for Angular2 apps? Something like the [jQuery QueryBuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org), but a bit better integrated into the npm world.

Comment: why do you need a query builder, if you link angular app to api backend?

Comment: I need an UI element to help the user to build a certain type of queries. The jQuery QueryBuilder is more less what I'm looking for, but it has quite a few dependencies and uses bootstrap.

Comment: You can just integrate it inside an ng2 component, please check http://plnkr.co/edit/13rGVC?p=preview

Comment: @tschaka1904, what did you end up going with?  I'm in the same position.

Comment: @Alex I implemented a working version of Wael Ben Zid El Guebsi. But it is not in production yet. Have you dealt with this problem?

Comment: I just wrote a simpler version for myself.  I settled on not needing the more complex logic in the jQuery QueryBuilder, so I just built a simpler version using an array of a custom modal that I iterate using ngFor.  When I want to add/delete, the buttons call a function in my component that just delete the given index.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder

Answer (score -2):

I have done one with angular 2 and model form

https://github.com/tjhjqh/Angular2QueryBuilder

Comment: This is an empty repository.

Comment: It's an empty repo!!!

Comment: The link is working now, but there has been no commits for the last 2 years.

Comment: it angular-cli startup code